# Cassandra User Define Type CreateIfNotExists

Tags: c#, cassandra

Im new to C# Cassandra Linq

Is there a solution to CreateIfNotExists of UDT if not exists using csharp-driver.

My purpose is when a keyspace, table and udt is not exists it will auto generate.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateIfNotExists()` method of the DataStax C# Driver's Linq component generates the CQL to create the table (`CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX`) but not the user-defined types within a table.

Comment: thank you, do you have a suggestion to generate a UDT?